# Regex not counting min/max value properly

Tags: python, regex, validation

edit: I've simplified my regex to obtain the correct output (see answer below). I'd still like advice on why the regex in question does not work.

I'm trying to validate data from a .csv file, line by line. If it matches a given parameter, great. If not, bad. The line in question is the `username` line. The first `if` validates as it should, and second `elif` does not (which is intended).

I think that the value for `matchObj` should only be valid within the scope of the if statements, but I've also tried setting `matchObj = None` before running `.match`, but still did not produce correct output.

I've attached my entire code for reference. I'm coding this in Python3. Excuse the potential dumb question, I'm coming from Java/C.

```
import re

with open("input.csv", "r") as insert:
array = []
for line in insert:
    array.append(line)

for i in range(len(array)):
    tempList = array[i].split(',')
    print(tempList[0])

    if tempList[0] == 'student':
        matchObj = re.match('\d{3}[\s]?\d{3}[\s]?\d{3}', tempList[1])
        if matchObj:
            print('student = Right!')
    elif tempList[0] == 'password':
        matchObj = re.match('(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{12,}', tempList[1])
        if matchObj:
            print('password = Right!')
    elif tempList[0] == 'username':
        matchObj = re.match('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{3,20}', tempList[1])
        print(matchObj)
        print(tempList[0])
        print(tempList[1])
        if matchObj:
            print('username = Right!')
```

The third `elif` for `username` should return "Right!". It can include any A-Z character, case does not matter, or any digit. Should be between 3 and 20 characters. The sample input in my .csv is `user123`

Here is the .csv

```
student,999999999
password,abcd1234
username,user123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your regexp itself: `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{3,20}`

As far as I can tell, this is what the different groups do:

- `(?=.*[a-z])` - Do a look-ahead assertion on any character (except a newline) repeated any number of times, followed by a lower-case letter.
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - Do a look-ahead assertion on any character (except a newline) repeated any number of times, followed by an uppercase letter.
- `.` - Look for any other character next that's not a newline.
- `{3,20}` - Match that previous character anywhere from 3 to 20 times

So when I run this for example:

```
test_strings = [ 'Papa', 'papa', 'pA', 'pA!', 'pa&Pa', 'pApa', 'pa\nPa' ]
for s in test_strings:
    m = re.match('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{3,20}', s)
    if m:
        print('"%s" is good' % s)
    else:
        print('"%s" is BAD' % s)
```

I get these results:

```
"Papa" is good
"papa" is BAD
"pA" is BAD
"pA!" is good
"pa&Pa" is good
"pApa" is good
"pa
   Pa" is BAD
```

But if all you really want to do is verify that `tempList[1]` is a string made up of only alpha-numeric characters, then the simplified regex you put as an answer makes more sense.  In fact, since you're matching the whole string, the `^` and `$` seem redundant.

For what it's worth, here's a way you could do it in Python without regexp:

```
matchObj = tempList[1].isalnum() and len(tempList[1]) in range(3,21)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified my regex to make it work.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$`